# Node.js / Pino.js: How to rotate logs in a separate thread

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, pinojs

I am trying to use pino for logging in to my node app Server and I do have some large logs coming, so rotating the files every day would be more practical.

So I used `pino.multistream()` and `require('file-stream-rotator')`

My code works, but for performance reasons, I would not like to use the streams in the main thread.

according to the doc, I should use `pino.transport()`:

> [`pino.multistream()`] differs from `pino.transport()` as all the streams will be executed within the main thread, i.e. the one that created the pino instance.
> https://github.com/pinojs/pino/releases?page=2

However, I can't manage to combine `pino.transport()` and `file-stream-rotator`.

my code that does not work completely
-> logs the first entries, but is not exportable because it blocks the script with the error

> throw new Error('the worker has exited')

Main file

```
const pino = require('pino')

const transport = pino.transport({
  target: './custom-transport.js'
})

const logger = pino(transport)
logger.level = 'info'

logger.info('Pino: Start Service Logging...')

module.exports = {
  logger
}
```

custom-transport.js file

```
const { once } = require('events')
const fileStreamRotator = require('file-stream-rotator')

const customTransport = async () => {
  const stream = fileStreamRotator.getStream({ filename: 'myfolder/custom-logger.log', frequency: 'daily' })
  await once(stream, 'open')
  return stream
}

module.exports = customTransport
```

Comment: You can see more in this github issue: https://github.com/pinojs/pino/issues/1323

Comment: github ticket is closed :/ would need that also